# vba number type error

Tags: vba, numbers, conditional-statements

I have a simple problem with the following sub:

For A1 = 0.01 & A2=0.34 values on the "Sheet1" sheet run the following:

```
         Sub test()
            tmp = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1")
         If tmp < 10 Then
            MsgBox ("O")
         End If

         tmp1 = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2")
         If tmp1 < 10 Then
           MsgBox ("P")
         End If

         End Sub
```

The problem is that when the value=0.01 (please not the dot instead of comma) the condition is true BUT when the value =0.34 then is false which is not the eexpected result.

Is the format wrong?

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, you need to add more details

Comment: As Jean says: more information, please. An entire `Sub` that we can copy/paste in order to test would be useful.

Comment: I ve tried my best to give a good example

Comment: What are your locale settings?

Comment: And are the values in the cell text or number?

Comment: @VincentG This sample code works the same for both text and nuber. how can I find the locale ? For time is "Greek".

Comment: There is two place to look for locale. First the Windows locale settings (in control panel->Region->Formats->Additionnal settings), and second in Excel, Options->Advanced->Editing options.

Comment: As of the system settings (windows) the locale="Greek". I changed to German and reproduce the problem but I get the same results. Althought I run the NumberFormatLocal Macro for each cell, and I did get "Standard" for the first and "General" for the second value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to force conversion of A1 value into `float` type.

For example:

```
tmp = Cdbl(Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").value)
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer but no difference.I get the same result